# For loop to ouput a specific pattern

Tags: java, for-loop

Objective: Trying to output the following pattern using a for loop:

```
abcde
abcd
abc
ab
a
```

Current code:
Obviously this doesn't work but my idea is to get the value in i so that 'a' doesn't loop after that number. How can I achieve this?

```
char x;
int i;
for (i = 5; i>1; i--)
    {
        for (x = 'a'; x<=(char)(i); x++)
        {
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: `x < (char)('a' + i)` ?

Comment: Or the other way round: Make the inner loop traverse `x` from `0` to `i` and move the character conversion to the output: `System.out.prin((char)('a' + x))`.

Comment: Short version: `for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) System.out.println("abcde".substring(0, i));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the loop to stop `i` characters after `'a'`, you can do something like this:

```
for (i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (x = 'a'; x < 'a' + i; x++)
        ...
```

`'a' + i` is the value of the character `i` places after `'a'`.

Comment: Minor point, but in addition to this, the user's outer `for` loop would need to use `i > 0` (or `i >= 0`) in order to achieve their desired output too.

Comment: can't i put x + i instead of 'a' + i?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg That would not make sense. `x < x + i` will continue to be true until `x` overflows, since both sides of the relationship are increasing at the same rate.

Answer (score 0):

Erwin is right. You will want to change `x<=(char)(i)` to `x<'a' + (char)(i)`, as well as `i = 5; i>1; i--)` to `i = 5; i>=1; i--)`.